# Mathjax Display Of $1<x<2$

Tags: mathjax

Experimenting with Mathjax on my site, I face a problem when I type in

```
$1<x<2$
```

The outcome will be as follows

[image]

This, for example, has no issues.

```
$x<1\text{ or }x>2$
```

[image]

How do I make the first one display normally?

I have attached the issue at http://teach.sg/mathematics/additional-mathematics/mathjax/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `<` is used to start a tag in HTML, the browser considers `1<x` to be a `1` followed by a tag beginning `<x`, and everything up to the next `>` becomes part of that tag.  This happens long before MathJax has a chance to look for mathematics on the page, so MathJax is not able to process this math as you intended it.

You have already identified one solution (using `\lt` and `\gt`)  You can also just use spaces in most cases:  `$1 < x < 2$`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$1<x<2$`, use `$1\lt x \lt 2$`.